# $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a submanifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map with $f(0)=0$. Assume that $0$ is a regular value that is for every $p\in f^{-1}\{0\} $ we have $Df(p):T_p\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to T_0\mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective. Show that $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a submanifold of dimension $n$.

I found the problem [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300053/if-every-point-in-f-10-is-regular-is-f-10-a-manifold) But as I want to do using the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) and [implicit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) function theorems. So I wanted to show that $\forall\ p\in f^{-1}(0),\ \exists U$ neighborhood of $p$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to some ball in $R^n$ to conclude that it is a manifold of dimension $n$.

**My attempt**

Take any $p\in f^{-1}(0)\implies f(p)=0. $ We write $p=(p_x,p_y)$ with $p_x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p_y\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Since $Df(p)$ is surjective, by some permutation we can assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)$ is invertible and hence using implicit function theorem there exist neighborhoods $V$ and $W$ of $p_x$ and $p_y$ respectively and a smooth map $\phi: V\to W$ such that $f(x,\phi(x))=0,$ for $x\in V$. After that I stuck.

Comment: You mean for every $p\in f^{-1}(0)$ in the first paragraph.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Thanks, sir. I would also like to thank for your video lectures. Watching those video lectures gave me a strong command on multivariable calculus, and I would like to tell you that I am writing the solution manual for your book  Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds. Currently, I am a Ph.D. student joined this year only in the field of differential topology.

Comment: Write solutions for yourself, sure, but please be sure that you don't suggest that I have approved your solutions. There are some very challenging problems in there! Indeed, I would ask that you keep your solutions to yourself. The book is ruined for classes if students find solutions to copy — right or wrong.

Comment: I am writing for myself only for discussing among ourselves not for making it public.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Have fun learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map \begin{align*} \omega: \mathbb{R}^n & \to \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \\ x &\mapsto (x,\phi(x))\end{align*} is a chart on $f^{-1}(0)$. Let me know if this is unclear in any way!

Comment: I got this but the thing is that I want to show this by the very fundamental definition of manifold that says it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: A chart is by definition a local homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: How do I prove that it is a chart?

Comment: And second, thing is that $x$ is not in the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You should change it $\omega :V\to \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

Comment: Whether or not its domain is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just a detail depending on which particular statement of the implicit function theorem you're working with -- we can just say that it's some open subsest of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and call it $V$ if you'd like. If you unwind the proof of the implicit function theorem, you'll see that $\omega$ is just projection onto the kernel of the derivative of $f$ in the natural sense (which we then see to be the tangent space to $f^{-1}(0)$ at the point under consideration).